# How to trigger a form submission by clicking on a check box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, triggers, submit

I am using jQuery 1.6 and I would like to submit a form by clicking on a check box button.

That is, I have the following code that submits a form

```
$jQuery('#search_form').submit(function () {
  $jQuery.get(this.action, $jQuery(this).serialize(), null, 'script');
  return false;
});
```

and when I click on a check box which HTML code is

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" ... id="check_box_id">
```

I would like to *trigger* the form submission.

**How can I do that?**

Comment: Just a word of caution - causing form submission by means that may be unfamiliar to the user (i.e. by clicking on a check-box) may introduce a level of confusion. It does depend on the layout of your page,and how the check-box is labelled, but there are established (and expected) behaviours on the web and deviating from them isn't always a good idea. Out of interest, why can't you just use a submit button, as per normal?

Comment: @belugabob - Maybe you are right, but I think that in my form the user can understand that behavior (I think...). Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trigger the `submit` event by simply calling `submit` with no arguments:

```
$jQuery("#check_box_id").click(function() {
    $jQuery("#search").submit();
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method:

```
$jQuery("#search").trigger("submit");
```

As it looks like you're firing an asynchronous request in the submit event handler, rather than using the default form behaviour, I would suggest disabling the checkbox (or removing the event handler) in the `submit` event handler, and then re-enabling it in the success callback of the `get` method, to prevent the user from submitting repeatedly.

Comment: doesn't submit() really submit the form and don't trigger the .submit() handler? so he _should_ use trigger()

Comment: No, calling `submit` with no arguments simply calls `trigger("submit")` behind the scenes anyway, so it makes no difference: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L710

Comment: @James Allardice - How can I disable and re-enable the form on the success event?

Comment: really, strange. i had a problem with that in my current project but maybe it was a different error. thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Backo - Disable it before the `get` call with `$("#checkbox").prop("disabled", true);` and enable it using `false` instead of `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$jQ("#check_box_id").click(function(){
  $jQ("#search").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling submit() on the form with no parameters will trigger it to submit.

Most event handlers in jQuery share this; calling .click() will simulate a click, whereas .click(function...) sets a handler.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#check_box_id').click(function()
    {
        $('#search_form').submit();
    });
});
```